# How do I Join or compare to calculated columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, concatenation

I would like to Join On or Select In to find only the rows that match between the two tables on the DOC_VER column.

- Query A determines all of the Checked Out documents under a specific user ID.
- Query B determines which Checked Out documents have a specific Author.

The table in query A does not have an author value which is why I have to connect the tables to compare.

**Query A**:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT ( CAST ( DOCNUM AS INTEGER ), '_', VERSION ) AS DOC_VER,
    DOCNUM, VERSION, CHECKOUT_DIR
FROM 
    MHGROUP.CHECKOUT
WHERE 
    CHECKOUT_DIR LIKE '%\0257\%'
```

**Results A**:

```
DOC_VER     DOCNUM  VERSION CHECKOUT_DIR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
4246295_10  4246295 10      C:\NrPortbl\ATL_IMANAGE\0257\4246295_10.DOC
6376084_19  6376084 19      C:\NrPortbl\DMSLIBRARY01\0257\6376084_19.DOC
```

**Query B**:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT ( CAST ( DOCNUM AS INTEGER ), '_', VERSION ) AS DOC_VER,
    DOCNUM, VERSION, AUTHOR
FROM 
    MHGROUP.DOCMASTER
```

**Results B**:

```
DOC_VER     DOCNUM  VERSION AUTHOR
--------------------------------------
3027872_1   3027872 1       0001
3027872_2   3027872 2       0001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expressions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM MHGROUP.CHECKOUT c JOIN
     MHGROUP.DOCMASTER dm
     ON CONCAT(CAST(C.DOCNUM AS INTEGER ), '_', C.VERSION ) =
        CONCAT(CAST(DM.DOCNUM AS INTEGER ), '_', DM.VERSION ) 
WHERE c.CHECKOUT_DIR LIKE '%\0257\%';
```

However, if this is the kind of thing you will often do, I would recommend computed columns, perhaps with indexes:

```
alter table MHGROUP.CHECKOUT
    add docver as (CONCAT(CAST(DOCNUM AS INTEGER ), '_', VERSION ));

alter table MHGROUP.DOCMASTER
    add docver as (CONCAT(CAST(DOCNUM AS INTEGER ), '_', VERSION ));

create index idx_checkout_docver on MHGROUP.CHECKOUT(docver);
create index idx_docmaster_docver on MHGROUP.docmaster(docver);
```

Then you can just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM MHGROUP.CHECKOUT c JOIN
     MHGROUP.DOCMASTER dm
     ON c.docver = dm.docver
WHERE c.CHECKOUT_DIR LIKE '%\0257\%';
```

EDIT:

As suggested by Jamie, the best solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM MHGROUP.CHECKOUT c JOIN
     MHGROUP.DOCMASTER dm
     ON c.docnum = dm.docnum and c.version = dm.version
WHERE c.CHECKOUT_DIR LIKE '%\0257\%';
```

Comment: is this any different than `docnum = docnum and version = version`?

Comment: @JamieD77 . . . That is a better solution.  When I answered, I didn't actually pay attention to the fact that the logic for the two expressions is the same.  I've edited the answer (although I would happily upvote an answer that you write).